# How to log to a text file when a button is pressed?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, button, logging

I am currently working on a small incremental interface. I have two buttons, `up` and `down`. If I press the `up` button, the number will be increased by 1 and if I press the `down` button the number will be decreased by 1.

I am new to Xcode and don't know how to create a logging file or how to log actions.

How can I create a log if a user, for example, presses the up button? It should be saved in a text file like this:

```
Number at start: 001 - button pressed: [up], new number: 002;
```

Thanks.

Comment: (I've retagged your question.  It has nothing to do with Xcode and everything to do with Cocoa.)  In any event, what have you tried?  Are you able to change your value and just need help writing a file?  Are you using an NSStepper, which is designed to do number increment/decrement?  Show your code!

Answer (score 0):

When initializing your class:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *rootPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

NSString *logFilePath = [path stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"log.txt"];
if(![fm fileExistsAtPath:logFilePath]) {
  unsigned char data = {' '};
  [fm createFileAtPath:logFilePath contents:[NSData dataWithBytes:&data length:1] attributes:nil];
}

NSFileHandle *logFile = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForUpdatingAtPath:logFilePath];
```

Then keep a handle to the logFile, and when it's time to log. Assuming the `count` and `oldCount' variables have your current and previous counts:

```
NSString *message = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Number at start: %i - button pressed: [%@], new number: %i\n", oldCount, count > oldCount ? @"up" : @"down", count];
NSData *dataLog = [message dataUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
[logFile seekToEndOfFile];
[logFile writeData:dataLog];
```